# I have encountered segmentation error when attempting to replace the tabs from entered strings with spaces

Tags: c

I have experienced some problem with segmentation when I'm learning through C, my aim is to swap the tabs in the program with spaces:

I have used the get_line template and modified the code to suit the situation. Here is the whole coded solution:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define MAXLINE 1000

char line[MAXLINE];
char detabline[MAXLINE];

int get_line(void);

int main(void){
    int len;
    int i;
    int nt = 0;

    extern char detabline[];
    extern char line[];

    while ((len = get_line()) > 0){
        for (i = 0; i < len; ++i){
            if (line[i] == '\t'){
                printf("%s", " ");
            }
            else{
                printf("%s", line[i]);
            }
        }
    } 

    return 0;

}

int get_line(void){
    int c, i, nt;

    nt = 0;

    extern char line[];

    for (i = 0; i < (MAXLINE - 1) && (c = getchar()) != EOF && ((c != '\t') || (c != '\n')); ++i){
        line[i] = c;
    }

    if (c == '\n'){
        line[i] = c;
        ++i;
    }
    else if (c == '\t'){
        ++nt;
    }

    line[i] = '\0';

    return i;
}
```

The problem is to locate which memory isn't allocated correctly. I may have some redundant code in the solution by the way.

Comment: the posted code does not cleanly compile!  Several of the warning messages from the compiler are critical.  like using the wrong output format specifier when calling `printf()`.  When compiling, always enable the warnings, then fix those warnings.  ( for `gcc`, at a minimum use: `-Wall -Wextra -Wconversion -pedantic -std=gnu11` )  Note: other compilers use different options to obtain the same output.

Comment: Could you provide text sample which leads to this problem?

Comment: Why are all the references to the 'file scope' variables being declared as `extern` in the functions?

Comment: `(c != '\t') || (c != '\n')` is always true

Comment: regarding: `if (line[i] == '\t'){
                printf("%s", " ");`  When a tab is encountered, wouldn't you actually want to insert 'just enough' spaces to bring the output up to the next tab stop (usually there is a tab stop every 8 character positions with the first tab stop at column 9)

Comment: The variable `nt` is being used as a counter that gets incremented under certain conditions.  However, it is never used for anything

Comment: @user3629249 `nt` is used initially as a test value to check the number of tabs.

Comment: @user3629249, the practice question requires the use of `extern` function to declare variables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

regarding:

```
for (i = 0; i < (MAXLINE - 1) && (c = getchar()) != EOF && ((c != '\t') || (c != '\n')); ++i){
```

this expression:

```
(c != '\t')
```

will result in no tab character ever being in the `line[]` array.

this expression:

```
(c != '\n')
```

will result in no newline character sequence ever being in the `line[]` array.

then, due those expressions, the `line[]` array will not be updated (ever again) when a tab or a newline is encountered due to those expressions causing an early exit from the `for()` loop

The following proposed code:

1. cleanly compiles
2. performs the desired functionality

and now, the proposed code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define MAXLINE 1000

char line[MAXLINE];

int main(void)
{
    int i = 0;

    int ch;
    while ( i< MAXLINE-1 && (ch = getchar()) != EOF  && ch != '\n' )
    {
        if ( ch == '\t')
        {
            line[i] = ' ';
        }

        else
        {
            line[i] = (char)ch;
        }
        i++;
    } 

    printf( "%s\n", line );
}
```

Post a comment if you want further details about the proposed code.